# Redirect Loop on IE6

Tags: jquery-address

I've been using Jquery address in one of my project and everything works great but when I tried it in IE6, the behavior is very weird.

When I try to visit 
http://www.local.test.com/?param=123

it loops infinitely:
http://www.local.test.com/#/?param=123#/?param=123#/?param=123#/?param=123#/?param=123#/

By the way, here is my jquery initialization

```
(function($){ 
//JQUERY ADDRESS Initialization
var init = true;
state = window.history.pushState !== undefined;

  $.address.state('/').init(function(event) {
     $('.address').address();
  }).change(function(event) {
      if (state && init) {
          init = false;
          //handleRequest();
    } 
      route();
  });
if (!state) {
}

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Just as a side note... Unless someone is forcing you to develop for IE6, I would say it's not worth it. At best, show them a message about using an out-of-date browser.

Comment: actually it's working on IE6, checkout their sample demo:

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/api/#/section/?id=2.2

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm in 2013 and the nearest museum that has IE6 installed is a long walk.

Answer (score 0):

Drop IE6 support. I know this doesn't answer your question, but it's *the* answer *to* your question.